# Where were these characters during their conversation?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 7 episode 7, we see

> Bronn and Jaime on the battlements of some castle/walled city looking at the ranks of Unsullied and then Dothraki cavalry.

Where were they? I thought that:

> Dany decided not to send the Unsullied and Dothraki to King's Landing.

Very soon afterwards these two characters are then seen in

> King's Landing

Comment: Also note that if these characters aren't in Kings Landing and are some other place where the Unsullied are that doesn't mean that the soon afterwards episode timeline is soon afterwards in universe timeline.

Comment: I think Dany decided not to send them to King's Landing earlier in the season to Siege it as Tyrion suggested because after losing allies and battles it became a greater risk. But this meeting is a show of force, as well as a clear statement that although she could fight the battle that that moment she is serious about choosing not to.

Comment: "I'll go to King's Landing. But not alone."

Comment: @Sidney - thank you. (Yes, a comment that doesn't add anything, but there you go).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## King's Landing

This is confirmed with Cersei and Jaime's conversation later on:

> **Cersei:** How many dragons did you see at the pit?
>
> **Jaime:** Two.
>
> **Cersei:** What happened to the third?
>
> **Jaime:** For all we know, it's guarding her fleet!
>
> **Cersei:** **She came here with her dragons and her Dothraki and her Unsullied. She came here to show us all her power**.
> <sub>***Season
>   7 Episode 7 - The Dragon and the Wolf***</sub>

Answer (score 29):

It's evident that it is King's Landing from the surroundings alone:

[image]

You can see the Red Keep on far-left Corner, atop Aegon's High Hill. The Unsullied are holding positions outside the city. So it's evident that it's King's Landing.

Later Cersei and Qyburn have this conversation:

> CERSEI: Why isn't she with them?
>
> QYBURN: I'm afraid I don't know, Your Grace. No one has seen her.
>
> CERSEI: And the rest of them?
>
> QYBURN: **They're on their way to the Dragonpit now**.

Dragonpit is in King's Landing, on Rhaenys' Hill.

Later when Tyrion goes to meet Cersei alone, he meets her in their Father's old office, in Tower of the Hand, inside Redkeep.

[image]

Comment: The second half of your answer refers to the main group i.e. Jon, Tyrion etc. And they arrived by boat, alone by the looks of it, so that doesn't seem relevant to where the Unsullied are. Though good spot with the Red Keep in the background +1

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Since they were all at one place, I just wanted to compile as much evidence there was in the episode for it being KL.

Comment: I agree just thought it was worth mentioning. If you want you can use the quote I have used in my answer to make yours more complete.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Oh no that's fine, there are a number of questions where answers complement each other.

Comment: Didn't recognise the Red Keep by it's silhouette, plus King's Landing (to me) always seems to be shown by it harbour, and not often by it's wall overlooking green field, which reminded me of Highgarden or Castelly Rock (and I knew it was neither of those).

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained where it is.  You said you didn't think that was the place:

> Dany decided not to send the Unsullied and Dothraki to King's Landing.

This is true, but then

> The troops that she did send (from the Tyrells and Martells) were sunk and/or captured.  Instead of sending the Unsullied to King's Landing, she had sent them to Casterly Rock.  And the Lannister army went to Highgarden (Tyrells).  The Lannisters went back to King's Landing and she sent the Dothraki there with her dragons.  The Unsullied reached King's Landing later, although they started about the same distance as the Lannister army.

You should also realize that what you're seeing is months later.  Conditions changed, so her decision changed.  It seems like less of a time, because comparatively little was shown happening in between.  But there's been something like a month or so between most episodes this year.

> One episode, Jon Snow is practically dead.  The next he's up and moving without issue.  One episode, the Unsullied are on the east side of the land with Daenerys.  Then they're on the other side, with ships.  Then they're back on the same side at King's Landing.

Those things take months.  It's not like our world where you can hop on a plane and be on the other side of the planet tomorrow.  But in story terms, they go directly from one place to another and skip the travel between.